# How to submit file, loop only over form elements having name in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How to implement file upload in jqGrid using dataProxy from http://jqgrid-php.net below?

Running code below causes exception

```
Unable to get value of the property 'removeAttr': object is null or undefined
```

at line

```
$(this).data('name', $(this).attr('name')).removeAttr('name');
```

as show in comment in code.

It looks like ele (form) contains elements without name which causes this exception.
How to fix this code ?
How to change this code so that it loops (saves/restores name) only over elements which have name.

```
var dataProxyAjax = function (opts, act) {  // from http://jqgrid-php.net
    opts.url = $(this).getGridParam('url');
    //use normal ajax-call for del
    if (act.substring(0, 4) == 'del_') {
        $.ajax(opts);
    }
    opts.iframe = true;
    var $form = $('#FrmGrid_' + $(this).getGridParam('id'));
    var ele = $form.find('INPUT,TEXTAREA').not(':file');
    //Prevent non-file inputs double serialization
    ele.each(function () {
        // todo: how to fix the error: Unable to get value of the property 'removeAttr': object is null or undefined 
        $(this).data('name', $(this).attr('name')).removeAttr('name');
    });
    //Send only previously generated data + files
    $form.ajaxSubmit(opts);
    //Set names back after form being submitted
    setTimeout(function () {
        ele.each(function () {
            $(this).attr('name', $(this).data('name'));
        });
    }, 200);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to set the value of something that isnt a value.  removeAttr just removes the attr...it seems like you are trying to set the data of 'name' for (this) element to be equal to (this) but with the attr 'name' removed. I'm not sure that makes a lot of sense.

try:

```
ele.each(function () {
        // todo: how to fix the error: Unable to get value of the property 'removeAttr': object is null or undefined 
        var theName = $(this).attr('name');
        $(this).removeAttr('name');
        $(this).data('name', theName);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do but hopefully this helps explain your problem.

> How to change this code so that it loops (saves/restores name) only over elements which have name.

```
ele.each(function () {
    // "only over elements which have name"
    if ($(this).hasAttr('name')) {
        // if it has a name do something with it
    }
});
```

However, if an HTML object doesn't have a name it won't throw an exception, it will just appear as undefined.  Shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZF3uC/1/

```
$(this).data('name', $(this).attr('name')).removeAttr('name');
```

This is throwing the exception because what you're doing here is saying, give me the `name` property of the `name` attribute of the HTML element stored in `$(this)` then remove that attribute.

The problem is the `name` attribute doesn't exist so `$(this).data('name', $(this).attr('name'))` is returning an undefined object which has no method called `removeAttr`

You can see how this is happening here http://jsfiddle.net/ZF3uC/5/